# Array in Array Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the right notation to store a array in a array in a Javascript Object?

Something like this:

```
let playfield = {
    rows: [
      boxes: []
    ],
  }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Remove `boxes:`

Comment: Close, it looks like `rows:[[]]`

Comment: or make `rows` an object instead of array or wrap `boxes` in object  Not enough known about your use case

Answer (score 2):

Multi-dimensional arrays have no properties like objects, it's just arrays in an array:

```
let playfield = {
    rows: [[], [], []],
  }
```